# out of memory reading and grouping csv file contains 300M number of row and group by dask.dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dask

I am new to Dask and having some troubles with it.
pandas can't fit in the memory, so I switch to use Dask.dataframe, What I expect is that Dask will process things in small chunks that can be fit in the memory. But Dask still uses up all of the memory.
It constantly leads to '**process killed**'

```
#import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np
import timeit
header =['DATE','IMSI','WEBSITE','LINKUP','LINKDOWN','COUNT','CONNECTION']
df = dd.read_csv('/home/mahmoudod/Desktop/to_dict/text1.txt'
                ,names = header
                ,header=0
                )
df.columns.str.strip()
df.DATE = dd.to_datetime(df.DATE, errors='coerce')
group = df.groupby(['IMSI','WEBSITE']).agg({'DATE':[max, min,'count']
    ,'LINKUP':'sum'
    , 'LINKDOWN':'sum'
    , 'COUNT':'sum'
    ,'CONNECTION':'sum'
            }).compute()
group.to_csv('/home/mahmoudod/Desktop/to_dict/output.txt')
print(df.info)
#print(group)
```

Comment: Did you try setting the `chunksize` to a lower value in the `read_csv`?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that your output result, `group`, is quite large and doesn't fit into memory.  This would be the case if you had very many groups.